# Linux C write serial port (Arduino) and wait for answer

Tags: c, linux, serialization, serial-port

Dear Colleagues.
I'm trying write C program for Linux to write serial port (Arduino) and wait for answer. I know, there was many Q about it on forum, but all I tried have the same problem - successfully write - but not read answer. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29248126/getting-wrong-data-in-serial-communication) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947413/how-to-open-read-and-write-from-serial-port-in-c).
I have found two separate files for [write](https://github.com/xanthium-enterprises/Serial-Port-Programming-on-Linux/blob/master/USB2SERIAL_Write/Transmitter%20(PC%20Side)/SerialPort_write.c) and for [read](https://github.com/xanthium-enterprises/Serial-Port-Programming-on-Linux/blob/master/USB2SERIAL_Read/Reciever%20(PC%20Side)/SerialPort_read.c).

I'm compile and run read file in one terminal window, and write file in other. Works great. But I can't merge them in one file to write and then wait for answer. The same problem - write, but not read.

Here is like I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
void main(void)
{
int fd;
fd = open("/dev/ttyS0",O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC); 
if(fd == -1)
       printf("\n  Error! in Opening ttyUSB0  ");
else
       printf("\n  ttyS0 Opened Successfully ");
struct termios SerialPortSettings;  
tcgetattr(fd, &SerialPortSettings);
cfsetispeed(&SerialPortSettings,B9600);
cfsetospeed(&SerialPortSettings,B9600);
        /* 8N1 Mode */
SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; 
SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |=  CS8;
SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; 
SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;
SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
SerialPortSettings.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;/*No Output Processing*/
        /* Setting Time outs */
SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VMIN] = 10; /* Read at least 10 characters */
SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; /* Wait indefinetly   */
if((tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&SerialPortSettings)) != 0)
    printf("\n  ERROR ! in Setting attributes");
else
    printf("\n  BaudRate = 9600 \n  StopBits = 1 \n  Parity   = none");

char write_buffer[] = "Hello/n";
int  bytes_written  = 0;
printf("\n  %s written to ttyUSB0",write_buffer);
printf("\n  %d Bytes written to ttyUSB0", bytes_written);
printf("\n +----------------------------------+\n\n");          
//tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH); /* Discards old data in the rx buffer            */
char read_buffer[32];
int  bytes_read = 0;
int i = 0;

write(fd,write_buffer,sizeof(write_buffer));/* use write() to send data to port   */
usleep ((8 + 25) * 100);            /* Delay */
read(fd,&read_buffer,32);            /* Read the data                   */
printf("\n\n  Bytes Rxed -%d", bytes_read); /* Print the number of bytes read */
printf("\n\n  ");
for(i=0;i<bytes_read;i++)    /*printing only the received characters*/
        printf("%c",read_buffer[i]);
printf("\n +----------------------------------+\n\n\n");
close(fd); /* Close the serial port */
}
```

Thanks for your help, Have a nice day.

Comment: You have a variable called `bytes_read` that is initialized to `0`. Nothing in the code changes that value.

Comment: "It doesn't work" - what happens instead?

Comment: Don't ignore the result from system calls.  Especially, don't ignore the result returned by read().

Comment: The statement `read(fd,&read_buffer,32)` should be corrected to `bytes_read = read(fd, read_buffer, 32)` per comment by @user3386109, and to remove indirection of array.

Comment: Don't wait answer, check message ending delimiter. waste system resources but gained maximum connectivity.

Comment: Your code has the same initialization bug as in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944461/linux-reading-data-from-uart

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable called `bytes_read` that is initialized to `0`. Nothing in the code changes that value.
                    – user3386109

The statement `read(fd,&read_buffer,32)` should be corrected to `bytes_read = read(fd, read_buffer, 32)` …
                    – sawdust